# Suggestions for tricky string in pandas row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am in the middle of processing weather data and I am still learning how to use pandas efficiently... I have a pandas data set where I have a row of wind speeds and directions formatted. The issue is the string format of the directions. The current format of the wind speed and direction column df['WindDirSpeed'] is as follows:

```
            IssueDatetime                                Regions  \
0     2018-01-01 06:00:00                            SOUTH COAST   
1     2018-01-01 06:00:00                            SOUTH COAST   
2     2018-01-01 06:00:00                            SOUTH COAST   
3     2018-01-01 06:00:00                            SOUTH COAST   
4     2018-01-01 06:00:00  EAST COAST-CAPE ST  FRANCIS AND SOUTH   
...                   ...                                    ...   
12833 2018-12-30 06:00:00               SOUTHEASTERN GRAND BANKS   
12834 2018-12-30 06:00:00               SOUTHEASTERN GRAND BANKS   
12835 2018-12-30 06:00:00               SOUTHEASTERN GRAND BANKS   
12836 2018-12-30 06:00:00               SOUTHWESTERN GRAND BANKS   
12837 2018-12-30 06:00:00               SOUTHWESTERN GRAND BANKS   

             forecastTime  forecastHour WindDirSpeed  
0     2018-01-01 06:00:00           0.0         SW35  
1     2018-01-01 15:00:00           9.0         SW25  
2     2018-01-02 08:00:00          26.0      SW15-20  
3     2018-01-02 15:00:00          33.0     VRB10-15  
4     2018-01-01 06:00:00           0.0         SW35  
...                   ...           ...          ...  
12833 2018-12-30 06:00:00           0.0         W25   
12834 2018-12-30 09:00:00           3.0          W25  
12835 2018-12-30 18:00:00          12.0         NW35  
12836 2018-12-30 06:00:00           0.0          W25  
12837 2018-12-30 12:00:00           6.0         NW30
```

I have attempted to write a function which extracts the direction and creates a new row with wind direction only:

```
def find_windDir(row):
    directions = ['VRB', 'N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW']
    for d in directions:
        if d in row['WindDirSpeed']:
            row['dir'] = d
            row['WindSpeed'] = row['WindDirSpeed'].replace(d,'')
    return row
```

Unfortunately this does not work because the "in row" finds all variations of the direction string.

Ideally I need the data set to be separated with wind speed and direction in separate columns:

```
 Dir WindSpeed  
  SW     35  
  SW     25  
  SW   15-20
```

Comment: Simple fix should be to order strings in "directions" by length (longest first).

Comment: `df['WindDirSpeed'].str.split('([VNEWS][REW]?[B]?)', expand=True)` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Dir'] = df['WindDirSpeed'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]*)')
df['WindSpeed'] = df['WindDirSpeed'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+\-[0-9]+|[0-9]+)')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
           forecastTime  forecastHour WindDirSpeed  Dir WindSpeed
2018-01-01     06:00:00           0.0         SW35   SW        35
2018-01-01     15:00:00           9.0         SW25   SW        25
2018-01-02     08:00:00          26.0      SW15-20   SW     15-20
2018-01-02     15:00:00          33.0     VRB10-15  VRB     10-15
2018-01-01     06:00:00           0.0         SW35   SW        35
2018-12-30     06:00:00           0.0          W25    W        25
2018-12-30     09:00:00           3.0          W25    W        25
2018-12-30     18:00:00          12.0         NW35   NW        35
2018-12-30     06:00:00           0.0          W25    W        25
2018-12-30     12:00:00           6.0         NW30   NW        30
```

Comment: Yeah, just realised I needed `extract` as opposed to `split`. The regexes I used were `Dir`: `'([VNEWS][REW]?[B]?)'`, and `WindSpeed` was `'[VNEWS][REW]?[B]?(.*)'`

Comment: The first one works correctly, second one's not working

Comment: Weird, what error do you get? It should be the same - just in that case the capturing group is "any number of any character _after_ the pattern"

Comment: Sorry they both work:
`df['Dir'] = df['WindDirSpeed'].str.extract(r'([VNEWS][REW]?[B]?)')`
`df['WindSpeed'] = df['WindDirSpeed'].str.extract(r'[VNEWS][REW]?[B]?(.*)')`